# Ant sshexec : building process stop

Tags: ant

I'm using ant to automatize the deployment of an application server-type.

The basics first steps of the deployment are working great, but (and It seems pretty normal), the ant build will stop when it launches the server.

Indeed my server is build around a loop, so when you run it on a terminal, it will block the terminal.
I've tried to do something like './exec > log.txt&' but it doesn't change anything.

I'd like ant to wait for the running to be finally ready, and then pass to the next task. Is there any way to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Checkout the ANT parallel task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html

Comment: Thank for the answer, and this parrallel task could be perfect if I just wanted to run my server, test it, and close it, but the issue is that I want to leave it run even when my ant build is over.

Comment: Finally I'm going to run the server once, do the test, send the log, and finally re run it so the build.xml won't finish but the server will be up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your build in [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and run the deployment as a post-build SSH step. For a more dedicated SSH solution I'd suggest investigating [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) which has a plugin for Jenkins.

Keep the build simple and hand-over the deployment to other tools.

Comment: I agree that it's strange to mix the build and the deployment step, but unfortunately I do not have any choice on the technology and have to use ant :/